# Hold Tight Connection Screen not Appearing (Unity SDK)

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-project-tango

Can't figure out why the Hold Tight screen is not appearing when my app starts? I've enabled the TangoUX component by placing it on a component on the stage. Everything is enabled on it.

Anyone else noticing this?

Comment: Yes I noticed it.

Answer (score 0):

What posture mode have you enabled in the Tango Manager/ Tango Camera?

What you could do is `debug.log` to make sure that you are successfully connecting to the Tango service; you can access the listener within the TangoUx from line 110 in the C# script

```c#
/// <summary>
/// This is called when succesfully connected to the Tango service.
/// <summary>

public void OnTangoServiceConnected()
{
    if (m_enableUXLibrary)
    {
         AndroidHelper.StartTangoUX(m_tangoApplication.m_enableMotionTracking && m_showConnectionScreen);
    }
}
```